# Moving window in Pandas to check for the specific range values

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, time-series

I have my time series data, I would like to check the data in a window of t+5 and t-5 and check whether it is in between 0.1 and 5 then need to mark that time as 1, similarly if the value in the same window is greater than 5 then it should return 2 else return zero.

I have tried like this, could you please suggest if there is more efficient way of doing this.

```
def my_func(arr,thres=5,lwthres=0.1):
    arr=arr.astype(float)
    if((arr[0]<thres) & (arr[1]<thres) & (arr[2]<thres) &(arr[3]<thres) &(arr[4]<thres)\
       &(arr[5]<thres)&(arr[6]<thres)&(arr[7]<thres)&(arr[8]<thres)&(arr[9]<thres)\
       & (arr[0]>=lwthres) & (arr[1]>=lwthres) & (arr[2]>=lwthres) &(arr[3]>=lwthres)\
       & (arr[4]>lwthres) &(arr[5]>=lwthres)&(arr[6]>=lwthres)&(arr[7]>=lwthres)&(arr[8]>=lwthres)&(arr[9]>=lwthres)):
        return 1   
    elif((arr[0]>=thres) & (arr[1]>=thres) & (arr[2]>=thres) &(arr[3]>=thres) &(arr[4]>=thres) &(arr[5]>=thres)&(arr[6]>=thres)&(arr[7]>=thres)&(arr[8]>=thres)&(arr[9]>=thres)):        
        return 2
    else:
        return 0

my_data=np.random.randint(5,size=100000)
my_df=pd.DataFrame(my_data)
tp=my_df.rolling(window=10,center=True).apply(lambda x:my_func(x))
df=pd.DataFrame()
df['value']=my_data
df['Type']=tp
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suppose something like this should be shorter, but idea is the same:

```
def my_func(arr,thres=5,lwthres=0.1):
    arr=arr.astype(float)
    if(max(arr[0]<thres) & min(arr)>=lwthres):
        return 1   
    elif(min(arr)>=thres)):        
        return 2
    else:
        return 0
```

Answer (score 2):

An improvement over @Alex's answer would be to compute `min_value` of array only the first time.

```
def my_func(arr, thres=5, lwthres=0.1):
    arr=arr.astype(float)

    min_value, max_value = np.inf, np.NINF
    for i in arr:
        if i < min_value:
            min_value = i
        if i > max_value:
            max_value = i

    if min_value >= thres:
        return 2
    elif max_value < lwthres:
        return 0
    else:
        return 1
```

Further improvement is to reduce the number of comparisons while computing `min_value` and `max_value` by comparing them in pairs.